# Dynamic Tab with Same data having different IDs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am working on a page using Jquery. I have a requirement of generating tabs dynamically(onclicking the '+' tab) .The content of all the tabs are the same(lots of textboxes and textareas). Now  as I generate new tabs the new tab should have this content but with different ids..(appending a counter would do).PLease help .

Comment: some code example? any demos? any tries?

Comment: @Rakesh - the idea is you show the work you have done, and the community will help...code samples important.

Answer (score 1):

1. create 1 template of the tab's content. hide it using css.
2. your tab header should have same class, e.g `class='tab-header'`.
3. when you click + , create new tab header. count the length of current .tab-header, and use the result in new tab that is just created for the id e.g `attr('id','tab'+counter)`
4. in the same time, clone the template on point 1 by `clone()` method and give the classname `addClass('tab-content tab-'+counter);` or just give it id `attr('id','tab-content-'+counter);`

Comment: Thanks bondy..............but i need every id inside the html content to be changed and appended as new tab content . sorry if i am being stupid.. I am a novice

Comment: Tell me how to clone and change all the inner ids too.

Comment: if u could give me a demo it would be grt

Comment: check here http://pendek.in/0475

Comment: :)...it is not what i meant ..I need to know how do we change all the ids after cloning

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jesseatkinson/EZgkN/6/

HTML

```
<button>CLICK ME TO ADD A NEW TAB!</button>
<ul>
    <li id="tab">This is a tab.</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var i = 0;

$('button').click(function () {
    var tabId = $('#tab').attr('id'),
        tabContent = $('#tab').html();

    tabId += i;
    $('ul').append('<li id=' + tabId + '>' + tabContent + " " + tabId + '</li>');
    i += 1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks jesse..............but i need every id inside the html content to be changed and appended as new tab content . sorry if i am being stupid.. I am a novice

Comment: Please tell me how to clone the content and increment all its ids and save to a variable

Comment: i have another question I am trying to make a tabs closable in jquery using ("#tab").tabs({closable: true}); but the problem is i dont want my first two tabs to be closable.or in other words , tabs should be closable from the third tab only. Help!!!